# Is this dictionary operation thread-safe?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I understand that regular dictionary read/write operations aren't threadsafe. What about this case?

```
class Data{ public int data{get; set;}}
```

and

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Data>();
```

Can this be thread safe?

```
await Task.WhenAll(dict
.Select(async t => 
    t.Value.data = t.Value.data+1;
    await somefunc(t.Value.data);
);
```

Is there a better way to rewrite this operation without using a ConcurrentDictionary since there is just one instance that I need this behaviour supported.

Comment: no, that absolutely does not look thread-safe; I would expect it to fail readily if someone mutates the contents while the implied iterator is iterating

Comment: You would have to `lock` all access to a dictionary to make the code thread-safe. What's wrong with using `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: Enumerating a collection is never a thread-safe operation unless the collection advertises that it is. This is true even when individual operations on the collection are thread-safe (which is not the case for `Dictionary`). The reason for this is fairly simple: ensuring thread-safe enumeration requires some sort of versioning or copy mechanism, which comes at a considerable cost. Note that `ConcurrentDictionary` provides an enumerator that is thread-safe in the sense that it will work, but explicitly does not guarantee snapshot semantics. Whether that's good enough for your case depends.